# Updating current value in ActiveRecord (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

in my application lots of objects are already preloaded by Rails.

Now I like to update some of these object attributes. Unfortunately some of these objects are related to the same object in my database. When I add a value to myObject.balance (`myObject.balance += value`), the attribute balance in *differentButSameObject* has still the same value.

One solution could be reloading the object. I would prefer to update the value like this:
`UPDATE myTable SET balance = balance + 10 WHERE id = 1`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use ActiveRecords update_all statement:

```
Object.where(:id => 1).update_all("balance = balance + 1")
```

Comment: Thank you! I use Rails 2.3.8 so my command is now `Object.update_all(["balance = balance + ?", value], :id => id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to your model. It uses the update_counters which performs a proper query (that does COALESCE, for instance):

```
def inc(counter, by = 1)
  raise "Cannot update column of a non-persisted model" unless persisted?
  self.class.update_counters(id, counter => by)
  increment(counter, by)
end
```